# Invariant Subspaces - Eigenvectors

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following function: $\rho : C_4 \rightarrow GL_2(\Bbb C)$

$\rho(e) = \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\ 
   \end{pmatrix} $

$\rho(x) =  \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & i \\
   i & 0 \\ 
   \end{pmatrix} $

$\rho(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
   -1 & 0 \\
   0 & -1 \\ 
   \end{pmatrix} $

$\rho(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & -i \\
   -i & 0 \\ 
   \end{pmatrix} $

I have shown that $(\Bbb C^2,\rho)$ is a representation, and I have found eigenvalues and eigenvectors for all four matrices.

Each matrix has the same two eigenvectors:

$\  \begin{pmatrix}
   1 \\
   2 \\ 
   \end{pmatrix} $ or $\ \begin{pmatrix}
   1 \\
   -2 \\ 
   \end{pmatrix} $

Now, I have to find a $1$-dimensional subspace of $(\Bbb C^2,\rho)$, but my two eigenvectors are linearly independent, so I'm a bit stuck, because this would give me a $2$-dimensional subspace.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the matrices $\rho(e)$ and $\rho(x^2)$ are just $I$ and $-I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix, so these have *all* vectors as eigenvectors.

For $\rho(x)$ and $\rho(x^3)$, you probably wanted to mean the vectors $v_1=\pmatrix{1\\ 1}$ and $v_2=\pmatrix{1\\-1}$.

A one dimensional invariant subspace must be generated by an eigenvector.

So, now we have two pieces of one dimensional $\rho$-invariant subspaces: 
$\quad{\rm span}(v_1)\  $ and $\  {\rm span}(v_2)$.

Comment: Okay, I think I see where you are coming from.
Would I then be correct in saying that $(\Bbb C^2,ρ)$ is reducible, because I have a non-trivial subrepresentation?